# Is it possible pass from functional child component reference to Parent(Class pure component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have project where i need class components change to functional components, but project is using references to get access child components, is it possible to give reference of functional child component to Class parent component?

for example

```
const ChildComponent = ({ ref }) => {
  return (
    <div>Child component</div>
  )
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    ref;

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.ref);
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <ChildComponent ref={this.ref}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would use the hook useImperativeHandle.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

```
const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => { 
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        key: "value"
    }))
    return <div>Child component</div>
}
ChildComponent = forwardRef(ChildComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use callbacks to pass data from child components to parent components, i.e

```
const ChildComponent = ({
    callback
}) => {
    callback('data to be passed to parent component')
    return ( <
        div > Child component < /div>
    )
}
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ref: ''
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.state.ref);
    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            ChildComponent callback = {
                (ref) => this.setState(ref)
            }
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: but in that case, parent Component code should be refactored